# Javascript syntax errors swallowed and hidden in async/await functions

Tags: javascript, electron, syntax-error

I'm learning `Electron.js` and I want to use async/await feature in my code but I'm a bit disappointed because syntax errors are swallowed and silent which make my future projects a nightmare for debugging.

db module:

```
exports.connect = function(){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        connection = mysql.createConnection({
             host     : host,
             port     : port,
             user     : user,
             password : null, // or the original password : 'apaswword'
             database : database
        });
             
        query = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
        
        connection.connect(function(error) {
             // in case of error
             if(error){
                 reject(error);
             }
             
             resolve(true);
        });
        
        connection.on('error', error => {
            dispatcher.send('connection-error', error.code);
        });
    });
}
```

bootstrap module:

```
async function connectDB(){
    try{
        let connected = await db.connect(THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR);
        
        return connected;
    }catch( error ){
        dispatcher.send('connection-error', error);
    }
}

exports.init = async function( win ){

    dispatcher.init(win);
    
    try{
        const connected = await connectDB();
        
        /*if(!connected){
            dispatcher.send('fatal-error', "MYSQL NOT CONNECTED");
        }*/
    }catch( error ){
        dispatcher.send('fatal-error', error);
    }
}
```

This code is trying to connect to mysql and send error if it can't connect, but notice the syntax error "THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR" that should halt execution or throw error, but it doesn't and my code has no errors at all even if it can't connect to mysql.

Notice that if I remove syntax error my code works well and catches mysql connection error.

I've read everywhere that is normal behavior of javascript async/promises code, but I'd like to know if there is a solution to catch syntax errors to make my debuging easier. Thank you

Comment: You should get `Unexpected identifier` error unless: 1) That line is not in the running script (totally not there or is in a file which is not executed). 2) It is commented out.

Comment: I have no error at all and line is in the script because if i remove it the script runs well & if it's present it's failing silentely

Comment: Sorry I had an error in my post i'll edit it, you where right now please take a look at the string that should throw error

Comment: What if you replace the string with a `console.log('some message')`? Can you see the message in output?

Comment: Sorry I can see it in the console yes

Comment: OMG i'll edit all my post very sorry because my example is throwing error, please sorry again i'm so confused, i'll try to edit my head is exploding now :(

Comment: Sorry again i've had hard time to reproduce my issue after many edits, please can you see now i've tested it and it's failing silently. thank you for your patience. It should throw THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR is undefined but it don't

Comment: @MoksyMosky It's not a syntax error, it's a reference error (the variable is not declared). It is caught by the `try` statement in the `connectDB` function, which emits a `connection-error` but then just returns `undefined` afterwards. If you want to handle the error in the `init` function, you would need to re-`throw` it.

Comment: @Bergi thank you, your solution + Xaqron worked so now i throw error in both inint & connectDB & it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Xarqron & Bergi I made it finnaly work, I just had to throw error in both connectDB and init catch's

```
async function connectDB(){
    try{
        let connected = await db.connect(THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR);

        return connected;
    }catch( error ){
        dispatcher.send('connection-error', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

exports.init = async function( win ){
    dispatcher.init(win);

    try{
        const connected = await connectDB();

        /*if(!connected){
            dispatcher.send('fatal-error', "MYSQL NOT CONNECTED");
        }*/
    }catch( error ){
        dispatcher.send('fatal-error', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Do you advice to always throw error in every catch block so that debugging would be easier ? Because I had hard time to find this kind of bug without any console warning or error

Answer (score 2):

If you have a syntax error inside a `try/catch` block or you are using a `catch all` mechanism (i.e. `process.on('uncaughtException'...`) the syntax error would be swallowed:

```
/* content of test.js */

console.log('hello')
THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR // comment this line and run again

try {
  THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR_BUT_DOESNOT
} catch (err) {
  // using err will throw exception: console.log(err)
  console.log('error happened')
}
```

Now run the script with and without comment in the line specified:

> $ node test.js

So you are doing such somewhere in your code.

**PS:**

```
async function connectDB(){
    try{
        let connected = await db.connect(THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR);

        return connected;
    }catch( error ){
        dispatcher.send('connection-error', error);
        // throw error
    }
}
```

The `db.connect(THIS_SHOULD_THROW_ERROR)` is in `try` block while you don't `throw` the error. If `dispatcher.send` doesn't throw the error in some point that error is swallowed.

Comment: I've edited my post please can you see it again ? PS: I don't have process.on('uncaughtException'...) in main process and I'm using angular 8 for rendering

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer to show where you are doing this.

Comment: Thnak you @Xaqron you made me to the right path when I throw error in connectDB only it doesn't work I had to also add throw in init method so that error is shown in console